# SonarQube code coverage for Erlang EUnit tests

Tags: maven, erlang, sonarqube, code-coverage, eunit

I am using Maven to run EUnit tests on my Erlang project and then making a static code analysis. I do not know how to configure the coverage report path so that SonarQube could also show my code coverage results.

Answer (score 2):

In your Maven goals, append the following

-Dsonar.erlang.eunit.reportsfolder=*PATH-TO-YOUR-REPORT-FILES*

For me following setting worked

-Dsonar.erlang.eunit.reportsfolder=_build/test/cover